# How do you make an AJAX callback trigger another AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Is there a way to have the callback of one AJAX trigger another AJAX call? Or will that go out of scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure...

```
...
success: function(data){
     $.ajax({.....
}
....
```

and as stated before, your scope is captured by the closure.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this.  Closures keep everything in scope.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47773/matthew-flaschen), you can also use `setTimeout()` to repeat the AJAX call at a predefined interval, as in the following example:

```
function autoUpdate() {

   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url:  '/web-service/?no_cache=' + (new Date()).getTime(),

      success: function(msg) {
         // Add your logic here for a successful AJAX response.
         // ...
         // ...

         // Relaunch the autoUpdate() function in 5 seconds
         setTimeout(autoUpdate, 5000);
      }
   });
}
```